# Report Lab not producing/saving a pdf while using Google Colab/Google Drive/ipynb

Tags: jupyter-notebook, pdf-generation, google-colaboratory, reportlab

I'm looking to use Report Lab within a Google Colab but it doesn't seem to generate any files.

This is the simple code I'm running. No "hello.pdf" exists in my Google Drive.

```
from reportlab.pdfgen.canvas import Canvas
canvas = Canvas("hello.pdf")
canvas.drawString(72, 72, "Hello, World")
canvas.showPage()
canvas.save()
```

I have successfully mounted my Google Drive using

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the full path in the call to Canvas.

```
canvas = Canvas("/content/drive/MyDrive/hello.pdf")
```